# php prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql

```
    public function insert_data($array){
        $db = new MySQLi(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);
        $var = "adam";
        $stmt = $db->stmt_init();
        $query = "INSERT INTO `pages` (`name`,`text`,`image`,`meta_desc`,`meta_kw`,`meta_author`,`image_thumb`) VALUES (? ? ? ? ? ? ?)";
        $stmt->prepare($query); 
        $stmt->bind_param('sssssss',$var,$var,$var,$var,$var,$var,$var);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
```

my mysqli-> prepare returns false, and i dont understand why.

can any one see what i am doing wrong here?

thanks

Comment: Reminds me of the 'missing semicolon' discussion on the [podcast](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/se-podcast-05/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`VALUES (? ? ? ? ? ? ?)` should be `VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`

Answer (score 2):

Don't you need commas between `?` ?